# Android Thread stop randomly in the middle of process

Tags: java, android, multithreading, loops

As the question says, here's the code.

What I want to do basically is I have a list of array, says "myArray". This array contains stored time points in millisecond. Next thing is I want to call a method based on those time points. So, I need to run a time counter from 0 while the music is playing, compare the time counter with the time points in the array progressively (from first array index until finished).

The first method "timeCounter" is a method to start a time counter while a music is playing through MediaPlayer.

```
public void timeCounter(){
    Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            while(musicPlaying){
                startCounter(arrayPos);
            }
        }
    };
    Thread musicPlayer = new Thread(myRunnable);
    musicPlayer.start();
}
```

This is where the comparison of time counter and time in the array takes place.

```
public void startCounter(List<Long> array){
    elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - timeStart;
    if(elapsedTime == array.get(arrayPos)){
        arrayPos += 1;  //Continue comparing with the next number in the array
        Log.v("DEBUG", "TIME MATCHES!");
        if(arrayPos>= array.size()){
            arrayPos= 0;  //Prevent out of array index
        }
    }
}
```

I have the code running correctly and the result from the LogCat is correct.

Now the problem is sometimes the Thread is not running until the music finished playing (I have set onCompletionListener and set "musicPlaying" to false when music finished). The stopping point is totally random, sometimes when it's just started, or around 50%, or even when it's near to completion. Sometimes it doesn't even start!
I've been trying to figure out why but I couldn't find any info about Thread stopping halfway or such in anywhere. Thanks in advance! =)

Comment: It might be helpful for you to log a message when the thread finishes with the status of the `musicPlaying` variable.  I bet that @Tudor is spot on and `musicPlaying` is getting randomly updated between the threads.

Comment: Wait, if the Log message I put inside the Thread is still showing message even when I exit the apps, that means the `musicPlaying` is still true throughout the whole process, right?

Comment: @Gray Where should I log the message? Putting log in the looper flooded my logcat and the thread keep running and showing "true" for musicPlaying even when I exit the apps

Comment: I'd put the message after the `while` loop "when the thread finishes".  Just thought it would be helpful for you to make sure that `musicPlaying` was false.

Comment: @Gray I've put a log message saying "MUSIC FINISHED" and it's called. Anyway, thanks for your input, problem solved =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your `if(elapsedTime == array.get(arrayPos))` should be `if(elapsedTime >= array.get(arrayPos))`.

You need to remember that the millisecond timer does not necessarily have a one millisecond tick. On Windows, for example, the returned value will only change every 15 ms or so. You may therefore completely miss a particular time and therefore never get past that entry in your list.

Comment: Oh, that might be the case. OK, let me run some tests, will inform you later

Comment: Spot on! I guess using `==` is a bad practice for a counter. Thanks a lot! =)

Answer (score 2):

If `musicPlaying` is modified and read between threads, make sure it is declared `volatile`.

Comment: I've declared `musicPlaying` to `volatile` but the problem still persist.

Comment: thanks for reminding me to use `volatile`, there might be another error if I didn't use it.